# JBoss AS 6 - deleted ear and tmp directory content - still deploys my war

Tags: deployment, jboss, war, ear

I have no idea why JBoss AS 6 still deploys my war after I delete the ear from JBOSS_HOME/server/default and delete the tmp directory as well.  When I restart JBoss without adding my ear, it starts the deployment of my war even though it's not anywhere in the JBoss 6 directory!
This is so frustrating.

Does anyone know what else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Single jboss instance? Assuming the file had been removed completely, the only cause I can think of will be a clustered jboss.